# Automated way to set SEND VOLUME by day?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

We have a list of 100K subscribers and we want to send a maximum number of emails per day - but the max volume changes by specific day.

For example we want to send more emails Tuesday through Thursday, fewer on Monday and Friday and none over the weekend (as we're driving people to a call centre)

We have a list of dates and the associated send volume.

Also part of this request is to order the subscribers by `Contract Expiry Date`, and new names can be added at any time... this is where we originally thought we could 'force' the send volume, with a `SELECT TOP X# of SUBSCRIBERS` but I'm stuck on whether this is possible or not...?

We know how to re-order the subscribers based on the Contract Expiry Date but how can we dynamically chose the right send volume per day and make this process entirely automated?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround!

It's a two-step process that first assigns a ROW NUMBER to the entire DB using `ORDER BY` + `OVER` clause, then we select ROWS (using said ROW NUMBER) up to the maximum volume where our `SEND DATE = TODAY'S DATE`